# Передача состояния между ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Прувет ребята. У меня такая проблема.
Есть два ViewController на котором расположены TableView.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
На первом контроллере я заполняю таблицу из двух массивов с названием и значением (да наверно супер тупо).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я нажимаю на ячейку с именем "Марка автомобиля". Передаю через segue на 2ой контроллер имя ячейки. Во 2ом контроллере создаю путь к файлу plist , где у меня хранятся Бренди машин с моделями. Этот файл представляет из себя словарь; пример: Ключ - Ауди, значения - a8, a6, a5 и т.д. Во ViewDidLoad делаю проверку и если там "Марка автомобиля", то гружу ключи словаря в таблицу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь сообственно сама проблема. На втором экране скажем я хочу выбрать марку машины, нужно передать это на предыдущий экран, чтобы это значение отобразилось в поле detailCellLabel (как на картинке).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь нужно чтобы при нажатие на "Модель" загружался список автомобилей  соответсвующий выбранной до этого "Марке автомобиля". Как это сделать я не понимаю.
Может вы сможете понять что я тут написал и дать пару советов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще говоря передача данных напрямую между view controller легко делается **вперед**.

Т.е если бы вы передавали данные с первого контроллера на второй, то вы могли бы написать что-то такое:

```
// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueID") {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        let vc: DestinationVC = segue.destination as! DestinationVC

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here
        vc.carModel = carModel
```

Однако у вас передача данных идет **назад**. Для такого варианта решение будет несколько сложнее.

Делайте так:

Во втором контроллере, где вы что-то выбираете, объявляете callback. Локально запоминаете то, что будете передавать и вызываете callback с этим параметром. Например:

```
var callback : ((String)->())?
var selected: String = "alpha"

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            selected = "alpha"
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            selected = "beta"
        }
        else {
            selected = "gamma"
        }

        self.callback?(selected)
    }
```

В первом контроллере создаете локальное поле для хранения текущего состояния и перегружате метод prepare for segue:

```
var detail: String?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        let vc: SecondTableViewController = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here
        vc.callback = { result in
            self.detail = result // этот detail потом подстваляете в методе cellForRowAtIndexPath
            self.tableView.reloadData() // Даете таблице команду на обновление
        }
    }
```

Такой вариант будет работать. Однако обратите внимание на то, что часто может быть, что вам не надо передавать данные между контроллерами в таких задачах. Например, если бы это были настройки приложения, скорее всего вы бы при выборе на втором контроллере сразу сохраняли данные в User defaults/Keychain/базу, а потом по возращению на первый контроллер снова брали оттуда обновленные данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)