# Как перенести данные в следующий ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uiviewcontroller

У меня идея создания меню для Кафе в приложении, первый ViewController отвечает просто за блоки блюд по типу Закуски, Шашлык и т.п. Весь 1 контроллер я реализовал

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}

var items = zip(TupesOfMenu, typesOfImagesMenu).compactMap({ MenuItem(type: $0, imageName: $1) })

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}
```

`
Так же настроил саму ячейку

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imaegView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

var item: MenuItem? {
    didSet {
        guard let item = item else { return }
        titleLabel?.text = item.type
        imaegView?.image = UIImage(named: item.imageName) // Подключаем к каждой cell фоновую картинку с помощью массива с именами
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
```

Теперь получается, такая вот конструкция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее при нажатии на одну из ячеек, у меня остается только эта ячейка в том же ViewController'e, но мне нужно создать отдельный Viewontroller, котоырый при нажатии на ячейку будет открываться, оставлять саму ячейку и далее в виде таблицы у меня будут блюда, которые я уже потом добавлю, я не знаю как правильно привязать этот самый контроллер, перенести туда нажатую ячейку и управлять этим самым контроллером

Comment: [Этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981281/Передача-состояния-между-viewcontrollers/981356#981356) вопрос смотрели? В вашем случае решение будет похожее.

Comment: Если честно, я не совсем понял как это делается, не могли бы вы более понятно расписать как мне решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 2):

После того, как вы настроили второй ViewController:

1) Создайте переход (segue) из ячейки на второй контроллер, и задайте этому переходу идентификатор (например: "goToSecond"): [image: 1]

2) В класс TableViewController добавьте Extension UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource:

```
extension TableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count // items - массив данных MenuItem
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let items = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.item = items //send data to TableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

3) в классе SecondViewController создайте перемунную `var menuItems = [MenuItems]()`
и также подготовьте таблицу для заполнения

4) в классе первого контроллера после  метода заполнения ячейки добавьте следующий метод:

```
 // send data from 1st to 2nd VC
 override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToSecond" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            destination.menuItems = items[indexPath.row] 
        }
    }
```

Comment: у вас получилось решить проблему?если да, то отметьте пожалуйста

Comment: Да, все получилось

Comment: @SOUTHYYY Будьте добры, отметьте вопрос как решённый. Это сбивает с толку гостей.